# Assert not null of a Singleton Object

Tags: java, singleton, assertion

Is it necessary to Assert.notNull of a Singleton Object?

I have a class:

```
public class ComponentFactory {
    private static LibraryFrame libraryFrame;

    public static synchronized LibraryFrame getLibraryFrame() {
        if (libraryFrame == null) {
           libraryFrame = new LibraryFrame();
        }
        return libraryFrame;
    }
}
```

Now is it needed to use as:

```
LibraryFrame libraryFrame = ComponentFactory.getLibraryFrame();
Assert.notNull(libraryFrame);
// other part
```

Here Assert class is org.springframework.util.Assert.

If Assertion failed is there anyway to call System.exit(0) after failure occurred?

Comment: *(not an answer to your question hence the comment)*... **If** you really want to use a singleton, then you can dodge synchronization costs altogether.  For example by using the *"initialize-on-demand holder class idiom"* described in *Effective Java*.

Comment: Actually you never need an assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Assert is not necessary since the `LibraryFrame` instance will always be initialized at this point.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation for that class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html), it's really intended to be used by a method to valid its arguments. (That is, it's intended for the enforcement of *preconditions*.) You should have unit-tests for `ComponentFactory`, and they should assert that its static `getLibraryFrame()` method doesn't return `null`, but it's not worthwhile to assert this at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Well when you use the Assert class from JUnit, any method in there are all void, but it uses the JUnit framework to tell you if the test has pass or failed.

If this is method for unit testing, then you have accomplished your test, but if this were ment for runtime, then use a if condition.

Comment: As he stated in the question he's using Spring's `Assert`, not JUnit`s.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [initialization-on-demand pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) (i.e. lazy loading singleton) for your singleton.  In that pattern if the construction of the instance fails you'll get an exception, otherwise you'll get the object.

This improves on your solution in two ways: it doesn't have the overhead of synchronization and it doesn't have the overhead of the `Assert`.  Both methods throw an exception if the singleton object is not created - in your code you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` from the assert.

Using init-on-demand your code would be:

```
public class ComponentFactory 
{
  private ComponentFactory() 
  {
  }

  private static class LazyHolder 
  {
    public static final LibraryFrame INSTANCE = new LibraryFrame();
  }

  public static LibraryFrame getLibraryFrame() 
  {
    return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

To use it would still be:

```
LibraryFrame libraryFrame = ComponentFactory.getLibraryFrame();
```

...except you no longer need neither the `Assert` nor the `Synchronized`.